# Shape of a spinning chain

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, centrifugal-force

A length of chain (or massive string; negligible thickness; non-stretching, no rigidity, but non-negligible mass), possessing uniformly distributed mass, attached to a vertical spinning shaft by one end spins with the shaft at constant angular velocity. Centrifugal acceleration pulls the chain *mostly* straight away from the axis, but the chain is drooping below the attachment point level due to weight.

[image]
[image]

What type of curve will be describing the shape of the chain in vertical plane? A general idea of the type of the curve (parabolic, exponential, straight?) will suffice, although obviously a complete equation would be excellent.

Answer (score 1):

Draw FBD for an element of the chain of length $\mathrm{d}s=\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}\right)^2}\,\mathrm{d}x$ at horizontal distance $x$ from center of rotation. Write down equations for the horizontal and vertical components.

[image]

I get:

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} s}\left(T\,\sin\theta\right) = -\sigma\,g$$
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} x}\left(T\,\cos\theta\right) = -\sigma\,\omega^2\,x$$

Now use $\mathrm{d}\left(\frac{A}{B}\right)=\frac{\mathrm{d}A}{B}-\frac{A\,\mathrm{d}B}{B^2}$ to eliminate $T$ from the above equations and thus get an equation involving $\frac{\mathrm{d}\tan\theta}{\mathrm{d} x}=\frac{\mathrm{d}^2y}{\mathrm{d}\,x^2}$; using $\mathrm{d}s=\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}\right)^2}\,\mathrm{d}x$ to eliminate the arclength and I think you should make headway.